# How to resolve Unable to get provider androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, androidx, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

Getting below exceptions from the play store build.

```
(1) Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/xxxxx-2Azm3A2rIO11oMMvbUb7lQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/xxxxx-2Azm3A2rIO11oMMvbUb7lQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/xxxxxx-2Azm3A2rIO11oMMvbUb7lQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
           at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider + 6834(ActivityThread.java:6834)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders + 6332(ActivityThread.java:6332)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication + 6240(ActivityThread.java:6240)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 + 237(ActivityThread.java:237)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1916(ActivityThread.java:1916)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
           at android.os.Looper.loop + 224(Looper.java:224)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7113(ActivityThread.java:7113)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 537(RuntimeInit.java:537)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 928(ZygoteInit.java:928)

(2) Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/xxxxx-2Azm3A2rIO11oMMvbUb7lQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/xxxxx-2Azm3A2rIO11oMMvbUb7lQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/xxxxx-2Azm3A2rIO11oMMvbUb7lQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass + 134(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass + 379(ClassLoader.java:379)
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass + 312(ClassLoader.java:312)
           at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider + 121(AppComponentFactory.java:121)
           at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateProvider + 62(CoreComponentFactory.java:62)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider + 6818(ActivityThread.java:6818)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders + 6332(ActivityThread.java:6332)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication + 6240(ActivityThread.java:6240)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 + 237(ActivityThread.java:237)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1916(ActivityThread.java:1916)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
           at android.os.Looper.loop + 224(Looper.java:224)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7113(ActivityThread.java:7113)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 537(RuntimeInit.java:537)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 928(ZygoteInit.java:928)
```

- Multidex is enabled.
- Life cycle Gradle.

  def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0-alpha02"
      implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
      implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"

Comment: Yes already migrated..

Comment: i think do not use alpha dependency, try to use stable dependency